# unit vector orthagonal to two vectors

Tags: calculus, vectors

[image]How would I calculate the unit vectors here? What is the appropriate way to solve this?

I do not completely understand which approach to take. Thanks!

Comment: Have you heard of something called the cross product? I think a quick google will answer your question.

Comment: Alternatively, just guess your favorite two numbers for two of the coordinates and figure out the third.

Comment: once i have the cross product (-15, 14, -4) where do I go from there?

Comment: Divide by the norm to make a unit vector. But there may have been an error in the calculation.

Comment: the norm being one of the normal vectors here?

Comment: Ahh i mean (-15, 14, -5)! :)

Comment: The norm of $(x,y,z)$ is $\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$.

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cross-product is good in 3D. Another approach is to start by trying to find numbers $x,y,z$ not all $0$ such that $4x+5y+2z=0$ and $x-3z=0$.

We have one degree of freedom here. In this case, use the simple second equation and put $z=1$. Then $x=3$. The first equation now gives $y=-\frac{14}{5}$.

To avoid fractions, multiply everything by $5$. We get $(15,-14,5)$.

To get a unit vector, divide by $\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$.

For the other answer, multiply everything by $-1$.